# Inject Dynamic SQL statement within another SQL Statement in SSIS Execute SQL task

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis

how can I make Code A dynamic using Execute SQL Task in SSIS?

**Code A**

```
SELECT SUM(DuplicateCount) AS TotalRow
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(ID + CheckCode) AS DuplicateCount
FROM Tbl_CheckCode
GROUP BY ID, CheckCode
HAVING COUNT(ID + CheckCode) > 1
) AS U
```

I've tried on storing the code in an object variable so I could use it as follows.

**Code B**

```
SELECT SUM(DuplicateCount) AS TotalRow
FROM (?) AS U
```

However, seems like SSIS is not allowing this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if the count(ID+checkcode) group by id,checkcode is going to give you the results you are expecting.  Why are you counting like this?  select id,checkcode,count(*) from table group by id,checkcode having count(*) > 1 is how I'd expect to see that.

Comment: count(ID+checkcode) shows the count of the ID and checkcode combination. You cant use count() without an argument.

Comment: count(*) or count(1) will work just as easily...it's a little weird to see it as this and I was wondering if you were expecting something different as a result

Comment: it shows the same output anyway. that's not really the problem here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.

Under the expressions section of the Execute SQL Task Editor, I've set the following code as the **SQLStatementSource**:

```
"SELECT SUM(DuplicateCount) AS TotalRow
FROM (" + @[User::SQLQuery] + ") AS U"
```

And automatically, it generated the following code in **SQLStatement** under the General section:

```
SELECT SUM(DuplicateCount) AS TotalRow
FROM () AS U
```

Answer (score 1):

Use another variable to create your entire SQL statement, and use that in the Execute SQL Task.

```
@CodeAVar = 'SELECT SUM(DuplicateCount) AS TotalRow
FROM (' + @CodeBVar + ') AS U'
```

Comment: the thing is, @CodeBVar is an object variable. I tried using it in an expression and SSIS is throwing an error that data type object is not supported in an expression.

Comment: What does @CodeBVar contain?   Does it contain the string "SELECT COUNT(ID + CheckCode)..." or does it contain the resultset of executing that query?

Comment: It contains the string "SELECT COUNT(ID + CheckCode)..." that is stored in an object variable.

Comment: Then it should be a simple matter of changing the @CodeBVariable from an Object- to a String-type, since it is used to contain string data.